# how to test WSO2 web service with parameeter

Tags: wso2

I created a web service in WSO2 DSS server. I need to test this with parameter in try this service. This is my query:

```
select 
    vRosterX.TempID, shift.shiftcode, vRosterX.vRosterXno,
    vRosterX.empno, emp_tbl.EFName, vRosterX.shiftID, 
    vshift.vshiftcode, vdays.dname, shift.shiftname, alow.alowvalue, 
    project.pname, team.tname 
from 
    vRosterX 
inner join 
    emp_tbl on vRosterX.empno = emp_tbl.EMPNo 
inner join 
    vshift on vRosterX.shiftID = vshift.vshiftcode 
inner join 
    vdays on vshift.vdays = vdays.dcode 
inner join 
    shift on vshift.shiftcode = shift.shiftcode 
inner join 
    alow on vshift.alow = alow.alowcode 
inner join 
    project on vshift.project = project.pcode 
inner join 
    team on team.tcode = emp_tbl.TEAM
where 
    TempID = ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how have parameterized queries using WSO2 DSS please refer the [following guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Sample+Queries#SampleQueries-Sample1Usinginputmappingsinaquery). It explains how you can add input mappings (input parameters) to a query

Once you create the data service you can test this using the [try-it feature](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Service+Dashboard#ServiceDashboard-Trythisservice)